# JmixDataRepository not finding entries

Tags: java, database, repository, jmix

For some reason JmixDataRepository fails to find a single entity in the database, despite that I checked they do exist.

The code for the repository:

```
public interface TournamentRepository extends JmixDataRepository<Tournament_, Long> {
    Optional<Tournament_> findBySlug(String slug);
}
```

Tournament_ entity:

```
@JmixEntity
@Table(name = "TOURNAMENT_", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "IDX_TOURNAMENT__AUTHOR", columnList = "AUTHOR_ID"),
        @Index(name = "IDX_TOURNAMENT__SCORING_METHOD", columnList = "SCORING_METHOD_ID"),
        @Index(name = "IDX_TOURNAMENT_SCORINGTEMPLATE", columnList = "SCORING_TEMPLATE_ID"),
        @Index(name = "IDX_TOURNAMENT__ON_ROOM", columnList = "ROOM_ID", unique = true)
})
@Entity
public class Tournament_ {
    
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "IS_FINISHED", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Boolean isFinished = false;
}
```

The service calls repository here:

```
public Page<Tournament_> getPage(Integer page, Integer size) {
    System.out.println("Entities found: " + tournamentRepository.count());
    return tournamentRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size));
}
```

I added a print statement to do some debugging.

```
// Entities found: 0
```

But there is a record in the database.

At this position, I am stuck and have no idea of the direction to look for the answer. I googled the question but it seems nobody had this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to check if the user has permission to read the entity `Tournament_`.

There is an annotation `@ApplyConstraints`, which determines whether to use `DataManager` or `UnconstrainedDataManager` in repositories. The default value is true(use DataManager), and it's applied on interface `JmixDataRepository`. That means, if your user has no permission to read corresponding entity, the count result should be 0.

`@ApplyConstraints` can be applied on both Repository interface or method.

BTW, you can use https://forum.jmix.io to ask Jmix questions and the dev team is really helping there.

Comment: Yes, it turned out to be related to entity access permissions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In .security package of the project there was an interface annotated with @ResourceRole. It contained the list of classes and the level of access to them.

```
@ResourceRole(name = "AnonymousRestRole", code = AnonymousRestRole.CODE, scope = "API")
public interface AnonymousRestRole {

@EntityPolicy(entityClass = SomeClass.class, actions = {EntityPolicyAction.ALL})
@EntityPolicy(entityClass = AnotherClass.class, actions = {EntityPolicyAction.READ})
}
```

Adding the following line to the list solved the problem.

```
@EntityPolicy(entityClass = Tournament_.class, actions = {EntityPolicyAction.ALL})
```